# jQuery load(), not loading properly. How can i attack this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello people of StackOverflow, i made sure to thoroughly ready through the site before attempting this question and also muster enough courage to ask for help(I like to solve my own problems, but in this case i came to a hard stop).

So the "help" that i need is criticism and guidance, i don't think i have enough knowledge to find the issue. So far i'm attempting a website that takes in data from user and outputs the results, which i did complete but an issue arise when i press submit, it refreshes the page which i do not want. I came to the conclusion of using button and type 'button' to prevent it from refreshing, great! Now the user can enter his/her info and it'll spit out the result perfectly. Now this is where the issue arises(bear with me), although the results is correct and all, i want my site to allow the user to choose a different option if he/she decides so, so when i choose another option from the drop down and press submit, it does nothing.

This led me to researching the issue and it led me to a few possibilities, the jQuery .load() will not load because of a local and webserver issue? I want to put it out there that i am not using a database, this is just a simple site that spits out results depending on the user's information(i'll prvide the code snippets at the bottom). Also in the console i am getting this message :

```
BMI_ws.html?age=&weight=&height=:44 Uncaught TypeError: BMR is not a function
at display_gains (bmi_backend.js:27)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (BMI_ws.html?age=&weight=&height=:44)
```

﻿

​Another thing that i found researching is the mentioning of XML, and AJAX that can help me with this issue, but i just want this to be a simple site without a database, if i can just use jQuery to manipulate this correctly i'll be happy with that.

HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Simon's BMi Tool</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = 'jQuery_methods.js'></script>
        <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'style.css'/>
        <script src = 'bmi_backend.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = 'container'>
            <div id = 'header'>
                <h1>Simon's BMi Tool</h1>
        </div>

        <div id = 'introduction' >
            <div id='context'>
                <h2> Instructions: <h2>
                <p> To properly use this to its best potential, you should accurately put in your information so that it can provide you an accurate daily caloric intake. </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id = 'content'>

            <div id = 'input'>
                <h2> Caloric Calculator <h2>

                <form name = 'Values' >
                    <input id = 'm' type ='radio' name = 'gender' value = 'Male'> Male <br>
                    <input id = 'f' type ='radio' name = 'gender' value = 'Female'> Female <br>
                    <br> Age: <br> <input id = 'a' type ='number' name = 'age' min = '10' max = '90' placeholder ='Age #'> <br>
                    <br> Weight(lbs) <br> <input id = 'w' type ='number' name ='weight' min = '70' max = '250' placeholder ='Weight #'>  <br>
                    <br> Height(inches) <br> <input id = 'h' type ='number' name ='height' min ='36' max = '84' placeholder ='Height #'> <br>
                    <br> Activity Level: <br> <select id = 'activity'>
                        <option value ='0'>Basic Metabolic Rate</option>
                        <option value ='1'>Desk Job</option>
                        <option value ='2'>Lightly Active</option>
                        <option value ='3'>Moderately Active</option>
                        <option value ='4'>Active</option>
                        <option value ='5'>Extremely Active</option>
                        </select>

                        <button type = 'button' onclick ="display_gains()"> submit </button>
                </form>

            </div>

            <div id= 'placeholder'>
                <p>Maintenence: </p><p id = 'maint_daily'>0</p>
                <p>Lose .5 per week: </p> <p id = 'lose_half'>0</p>
                <p>Lose 1 per week: </p> <p id = 'lose_one'>0</p>
                <p>Gain .5 per week: </p> <p id = 'gain_half'>0</p>
                <p>Gain 1 per week: </p><p id ='gain_one'>0</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id = 'footer'>
            Copyright &copy; 2017 Simon Liu
        </div>

        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

JavaScript :

```
    var age;
var height;
var weight;
var activity;
var BMR;
var selection;

function BMR()
{
    if(document.getElementById('m').checked)
    {
        age = document.getElementById('a').value;
        height = document.getElementById('h').value;
        weight = document.getElementById('w').value;
        BMR = male_bmr(age, height, weight);
    } else
    {
        age = document.getElementById('a').value;
        height = document.getElementById('h').value;
        weight = document.getElementById('w').value;
        BMR = female_bmr(age, height, weight);
    } 
    return BMR;
}

function display_gains(){
    var value = BMR();
    var option = document.getElementById('activity');
    var text = option.options[option.selectedIndex].text;

    if (text === 'Basic Metabolic Rate')
    {
        return document.getElementById('maint_daily').innerHTML = value.toFixed(0);
    } 
    else if (text === 'Desk Job')
    {
        document.getElementById('maint_daily').innerHTML = (value*1.2).toFixed(0);
        document.getElementById('lose_half').innerHTML = (one(value) - 250).toFixed(0);
        document.getElementById('lose_one').innerHTML = (one(value) - 500).toFixed(0);
        document.getElementById('gain_half').innerHTML = (one(value) + 250).toFixed(0);
        document.getElementById('gain_one').innerHTML = (one(value) + 500).toFixed(0);
    }
}


function male_bmr(a, h, w){
    return(66.47 + (13.75 * (kg(w))) + (5 * (cm(h))) - (6.75 * a));
}

function female_bmr(a, h, w){
    var fbmr = 665.09 + (9.56 * (kg(w))) + (1.84 * (cm(h))) - (4.67 * a);
    return fbmr;
}

function kg(lbs){
    var ans = (lbs * .453592);
    return ans;
}

function cm(inches)
{
    var ans = (inches) * (2.54);
    return ans;
}

function one(val)
{
    var sample = val;
    return sample*1.2;
}

function two(val)
{
    return val*1.375;
}

function three(val)
{
    return val*1.55;
}

function four(val)
{
    return val*1.725;
}

function five(val)
{
    return val*1.9;
}
```

and lastly the jQuery.js :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#placeholder").load("bmi_backend.js");
    });
});
```

These are my working code for the site, i do have the CSS as well, but i don't think the issue lies in there. If anyone out there that can guide me on solving this issue, or direct me the correct path so i can research it and solve it myself i would be most grateful! Thank you!

P.S Sorry for this horrible post, it's my first time posting.

Comment: First step is normally to consult the documentation. Have you reviewed [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have a variable and function by the same name `BMR`. Within the `BMR` function you replace the function with the result of `male_bmr()/female_bmr()`.

To resolve try these steps:

1. Change the function name to something unique (e.g. `calculate_bmr`).
2. Change the code in function `display_gains` to reflect this name (i.e. `var value = calculate_bmr();`)

I don't think you need to load the script file separately since you're already including it in the page header.

Comment: Thank you H77, you saved my day. Appreciate your help! Will be using SO more!

Answer (score 0):

I think `.load()` needs html parameter not js file as you are doing here.

Comment: really!? let me try right now. thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: ahh that wasn't it, but good looks on that, something so simple that i forget sometimes.